# Why is Visual Studio better than VS Code at suggestions with Unity?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

So I was using Visual Studio 2019 to write scripts on Unity. But for some reasons, I had some unrecognized namespaces in my scripts. Then I switched to VS Code and the same namespaces were correctly recognized. So now I'm using VS Code.
The thing is that VS Code does not help me as much as Visual Studio. For example, if I write `newFunction()`, Visual Studio will suggest to create this function, whereas VS Code will simply show an error. Am I missing something ?

Comment: This is subject to opinion based answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VSCode is mainly a text editor whereas Visual Studio is a complete IDE.
A lot of programmers however prefer VSCode over Visual Studio due to it's lighter nature and it's marketplace, with which you can basically turn it into a full fledged IDE.
Here are some suggestions for C# and Unity:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tobiah.unity-tools
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kleber-swf.unity-code-snippets
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp

Personally I prefer Rider from Jetbrains as they have very tight Unity integration built-in, but it's not free.

Comment: Thanks I will try Rider as well.